# 15 Day rule in Mulesoft dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

Need help on Dataweave code for this. We want the Hierarchy version to be based on the 15 day rule. For example, (based on current date)from April 16 to May 15, the file will be sent with MAY in the file name. From May 16 to June 15, the file will be sent with JUN in the file name.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please clarify and provide examples of the expected output.

Comment: I need Dataweave code which I posted in previous post....   If current date(meaning you can consider today's date 19th) is between 16th day to 31st day of the current month and next month 1st to 15th day then my file name should be with 'JUL' like this   "Hierachy_JUL-2020_2020_06_19_16_41.txt"

Comment: You should edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear but my understanding is that given a date, you want to return a three character month name, the current one if the day of month is 15 then it should be the next month instead of the current one.

I created a DataWeave function to return that:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun month15(date : DateTime)=upper((if (date.day >15) (date + |P1M|) else date) as String {format:"MMM"}) ++  date as String {format:"-yyyy_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm"}
---
{
    now: month15(now()),
    june15: month15(|2020-06-15T18:03:01Z|),    
    june19: month15(|2020-06-19T10:15:54Z|)    
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "now": "JUL-2020_2020_06_21_14_24",
  "june15": "JUN-2020_2020_06_15_18_03",
  "june19": "JUL-2020_2020_06_19_10_15"
}
```

Updated with new pattern requested in comments which require a DateTime argument.

Comment: the current one if the day of month is 15 to 31  AND 1st to 15 for next month also should be returned next 3 character month.....  Today is 19th June right, then next month 3 character month name should be return as JUL.... ALSO for July 1st to 15th days also should be return 3 character as JUL

Comment: can you please provide the code with this format  {format:"MMM-yyyy_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm"}  rather than {format:"MMM"} ?   I tried but not worked for me.

Comment: The date handling seems to be exactly as you asking. Let me know if there is a case I missed.
You didn't mention the need for a time pattern. My script assumed a date, which doesn't has the time. When you used the time patterns it failed to find a time. The error message mentioned it. I modified my script to assume a date and to convert to uppercase the result..

Comment: Output:
{
  "now": "JUL-2020_2020_07_20_12_56", }

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: Output:
{
  "now": "JUL-2020_2020_07_20_12_56", }

This output is good for me but  two letter month 07 should be 06 only as current month. First 3 letters JUL is as expected but two letter month 07 in above output should be current month i.e. 06.  Could you please help on this ?

Comment: I hope you saw my last comment with complete information. If not, then I will post again.

Comment: That's trivial, just requires to format the details without increasing the month, and separated from the name. I just updated the solution anyway.

Comment: Did the last version comply with everything?

Comment: By considering your recent code, I used at Mule Variable as "Hierachy_" ++ upper((if(now().day >15) (now() + |P1M|) else now()) as String {format:"MMM-yyyy"}) ++ now() as String {format:"-yyyy_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm"} ++ ".txt".          I need to add as new requirement this timezone pattern   after now word as >> "America/Los_Angeles" .  Can you please provide code.

Comment: "America/Los_Angeles"   this should call from .property file.  I need this change and previous post change need to put into variable.  Please help.

Comment: Below code in Variable processor and working  but Time(HH_mm) is giving based on my laptop timezone(CST) rather than America/Los_Angeles(PST) which I put in property file and which I need PST timezone.Could you please help on this by modifying my code ?

 "Hierachy_" ++ upper((if((now() >> Mule::p('hierarchy.job.cron.timezone')).day >15) ((now() >> Mule::p('hierarchy.job.cron.timezone')) + |P1M|) else (now() >> Mule::p('hierarchy.job.cron.timezone'))) asString {format:"MMM"}) ++ now() as String {format:"-yyyy_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm"} ++ ".txt"

Output   -   Hierachy_JUL-2020_2020_06_23_15_06.txt

Comment: I'm sorry but you are keeping changing the question. You should really accept the answer if correct, and post a new questions for each new problem.

Comment: Sure, will do next time to accept the answer first. Thanks.

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks.